# create xml list with image icons in joomla

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla3.0

I desire to create a xml form field of type "list" which also contains images. So, form filed is like:

```
<field name="mylistvalue" type="list" default="" label="Select an option" description="">
  <option value="0">Option 1 (want icon here) </option>
  <option value="1">Option 2 (want icon here) </option>
</field>
```

Any help?